# next-intl package for Next.js with app router - issue with statically generated structure

Tags: next.js, static-site-generation, next-intl, next.js14

might be my mistake, but when I use the current version also for static export, the generated structure -

a) does not omit the "as-needed" default language folder
b) the files are named incorrectly (for example en.html instead of index.html)

```
/ (english default)
/de (german default)
/about-us
/de/uber-uns
```

... in the static export I would expect (among other files of course)

```
/index.html (english default)
/de/index.html (german default)
/about-us/index.html
/de/uber-uns/index.html
```

But the generated structure in fact is -

```
/en.html
/de.html
/en/about.html
/de/about.html
```

And that will not work the same way. Maybe there is something I am doing wrong in configuration, so I can share any part of the application needed to get a better result.

I tried multiple changes in the project configuration, but could not find solution neither in documentation nor in the app itself.

Comment: The middleware (that hide the locale) doesn't work with export output